# App Engine Frontend/Backend Instance "simultaneous API calls limit"

Tags: google-app-engine

It is documented [here](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/backends/overview), that

```
Backends are allowed to make up to 100 simultaneous API calls
```

What does this mean?
Does it limit the concurrency on app engine service call (like async urlfetch) or RPC call?
And what about Frontend instances? What kind of limitation do they have?
I googled around but didn't find information about that.

Comment: Having exactly same trouble. Did you find out something?

Comment: No. But I'd like to guess this restriction is on RPC level.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the error is exactly what it says. Google doesn't want to have Back-ends with that many simultaneous calls.

Front-ends which automatically scale don't have that limitation. From my testing I was able to get 2500 transactions a second call the front end. That scales up to dozens of instances, trying to do that with a single back-end instance would be painfully slow.

Also, you don't want to have the front-end call the back-end and do a heavy-task. I just have the front-end call the back-end to put tasks in a queue and the make sure the back-end has a background thread working on the tasks in the queue.

That way the front-end(s) are not waiting for a back-end to finish a task. You could get a bunch of DeadlineExceededErrors if the back-end is too slow.